# Angular ControllerAs syntax with custom directive

Tags: angularjs, typescript, binding, controlleras

Hello I have a problem in uploading an image .I use typescript so I tried to adapt a [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/JeJenny/ZG9re/). I found on the internet but the problem is that I don't use the scope  so the field 'myFile' is not being modified from the directive.I used the `bindToController` and `scope:{myFile'='}` but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code into the question? the jsFiddle might not exist forever.

Comment: myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;
            
            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use controller syntax for directive , use like this

```
function myExample() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: '...',
        scope: {
            myFile: '='
        },
        link: linkFunc,
        controller: ExampleController,

        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true 
    };
return directive

  function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
   scope.vm.myFile = ...
}
}
function ExampleController(){
var vm = this
}
```

Comment: .$apply(function(){ modelSetter(scope.vm.myFile, element[0].files[0]); }); the problem is here i changed but myFile is always undefined

Comment: do you try console.log `myFile` in main controller ? And you use  `$scope` in main controller , just use it in directive . In main controller try change to `var file;`  `$scope.myFile = file`

Comment: I don't work with scope in controller when i make scope.vm.myFile=something it works but when i try  
.$apply(function(){ modelSetter(scope.vm.myFile, element[0].files[0]); }); it is 'undefined'

Comment: Can you create a fidde or plnkr ?

Comment: I am working with typescript i think that types of 'element' in link function is not correct i put element:any i wrote link(scope:IScope,element:any,attr;IAttributes)